# How to determine wheteher these sets are open using continuity and preimage definition

Tags: real-analysis

Okay so I want some hints (not solutions) on figuring out whether these sets are open, closed or neither.

$A = \{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3\ \ | \ \ |x^2+y^2+z^2|\lt2 \ and \ |z| \lt 1 \} \\ B = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \ | \ y=2x^2\}$

Okay so since this question is the last part of the question where I proved that if the function $f$ is continuous then $f^{-1}(B)$ is open if  $B$ is open where $f: X \to Y $ and $ B \subseteq X $. I assume I am supposed to define an image of $A$ and $B$ and show that they are close/open then use this definition. But I am not sure how to define the functions. I have an hint for the question stating that I should use the fact that polynomials are continuous mappings and the fact that any norm $\|\cdot\| : V \to \mathbb{R} $  is continous. So for $A$ should I consider a norm $\|\cdot\| $ induced by $|\cdot|$ then the image of $A$ would be $(-2, 2)$ since this set is open, $A$ (its preimage) will be open? And for $b$ I define $f(x)=2x^2$ but that didn't  sound right... I don't know I am confused on how to take the first step. So any hints on how I should approach this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $A$, consider
$$
f(x,y,z)=||x,y,z||^2=x^2+y^2+z^2,\quad g(x,y,z)=z^2\\\implies A=f^{-1}((-0.5,4))\bigcap g^{-1}((-0.5,1)).
$$
(If  you think of $f$ as $\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}_+$ then $f^{-1}([0,4))$ will also be okay. Similarly for $g$).

For $B$, consider
$$
h(x,y)=2x^2-y\implies B=h^{-1}(\{0\}).
$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer so one thing I did not understand why did you pick the lower bound as $-0.5$ rather then $0$? Shouldn't $f$ always return a positive number ? For the second set $B$ so you have used the property that polynomials are continuous mappings right? So for $B$ is $h : \mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: I picked $-0.5$ (it could have been any negative number, not just $-0.5$), because I didn't want to exclude the point $(0,0,0)$ in the preimage.

Comment: Shouldn't the norm you have defined be in absolute value terms ? Also say we have the sets $(-\infty, 4)$ and $(-\infty,1)$ for functions $f$ and $g$ respectively then the inverse of these functions will not be defined for any value less then $0$? Also you have said $f^{-1}([0,4))$ will also be okay and the interval $[0,4)$ will be open in $\mathbb{R}_+$ right ?

Comment: It could have been stated using absolute values but I did it like this because your problem mentioned polynomials and $|z|<1$ is the same thing as $z^2<1^2$. $[0,4)$ is indeed open in $\mathbb{R}_+$.

Answer (score 0):

$A=\left\{ \left(x,y,z\right)\mid f\left(x,y,z\right)<2\text{ and }g\left(x,y,z\right)<1\right\} $
so that $A=f^{-1}\left(\left(-\infty,2\right)\right)\cap g^{-1}\left(\left(-\infty,1\right)\right)$.

What can be said about $f$ and $g$ if it comes to continuity?

What can be said about the sets $\left(-\infty,2\right)$ and $\left(-\infty,1\right)$
when it comes to open/closed?

---

$B=\left\{ \left(x,y\right)\mid h\left(x,y\right)=0\right\} $ so
that $B=h^{-1}\left(\left\{ 0\right\} \right)$.

What can be said about $h$ if it comes to continuity?

What can be said about set $\left\{ 0\right\} $ when it comes to open/closed?

Comment: So the restrictions are in fact the image of the functions that we create and the functions are the properties that define the set. So instead of defining the sets $A$ and $B$ the "standart" way we define them as the preimage of some functions. And these functions are the restrictions we put on the sets?

Comment: I wouldn't call a function on its own a restriction. It is more that the a restriction comes forth out of conditions that are 'put on' the function (e.g. like $f(x)<7$). When it comes to questions about open/closed then especially *continuous* functions are very useful. If you meet a set and must figure out whether it is open or closed then a first thought can be: can I find a suitable continuous function here such that the set is a preimage of some open or closed set under this function? If so, then you are ready.

Comment: Okay I see now but one thing I still don't understand. The fact that the set $A$ was defined for elements in absolute value appears not to have any significance. From what I see for the set $C = \{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3\ \ | \ \ x^2+y^2+z^2\lt2 \ and \ z \lt 1 \}$ it will also be true that $C=f^{-1}\left(\left(-\infty,2\right)\right)\cap g^{-1}\left(\left(-\infty,1\right)\right)$ is this correct ?

Comment: It is coincidence that the absolute value does not play a part in this. If things would have been different, e.g. with $\left|x^{2}-y^{2}-z^{2}\right|$ instead,
then we would deal with a composition of two continuous functions
:$\left(x,y,z\right)\mapsto x^{2}-y^{2}-z^{2}$ followed by the function
$\left|\right|:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ prescribed by $z\mapsto\left|z\right|$.
As composition of continuous functions this is on its turn also a
continuous function.

Comment: But even with $x^2-y^2-z^2$ the image will be $(-\infty, 2) \cap (-\infty, 1)$ ?

Comment: Not the concept *image* but the concept *preimage* is relevant here. As said in my answer the set $A$ can be written as union of preimages of open sets under continuous functions. That implies that $A$ is open. How functions look like does not matter as long as they are continuous.